# How to debug GCP `backend_response_corrupted` error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Springboot application running as a kubernetes deployment, exposed as a kubernetes `NodePort` `Service` using the default ingress controller provided by GCP. The problem is that I run into 502 errors when hitting the service's endpoint. Cloud logging reports it to be a `backend_response_corrupted` error. However, if I port-forward to the service, I don't run into that problem. How can I go about checking what causes the error?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide output of command kubectl describe ep -n your-namespace your-service

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this documentation:

[Troubleshooting load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs)

it contains general troubleshooting steps for cases like:

**Unexplained 502 errors**
If 502 errors persist longer than a few minutes after you complete the load balancer configuration, it's likely that either:

There's no [firewall rule configured to allow health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-http-lb-simple#firewall).
The software on the backends isn't running.

To verify that health check traffic reaches your backend VMs, [enable health check logging](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-logging) and search for successful log entries.

**Unexplained 502 errors**
Make sure that your backend instance is healthy and supports HTTP/2 protocol. You can verify this by testing connectivity to the backend instance using HTTP/2. Ensure that the VM uses HTTP/2 spec-compliant cipher suites. For example, certain TLS 1.2 cipher suites are disallowed by HTTP/2. Refer to the TLS 1.2 Cipher Suite Black List.

After you verify that the VM uses the HTTP/2 protocol, make sure your firewall setup allows the health checker and load balancer to pass through.

If there are no problems with the firewall setup, ensure that the load balancer is configured to talk to the correct port on the VM.

hope the guide is useful for your issue.
CHeers

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for the response. Fortunately, I was able to figure out the issue which was because of returning a response directly from another API call. Extracting the response body and sending it back alone worked for me.